# Solaris 8 GCC installation

Tags: gcc, solaris

I've successfully installed the package "GNUgcc", although when I type the command "gcc" or "GNUgcc", the terminal returns "gcc/GNUgcc: not found". I've run pkginfo -l GNUgcc, which returns 57 executables (seems like a lot?).

In /usr/local/bin, gcc exists. In /usr/local/libexec, gcc is the only folder that exists. Not sure where to go from here

Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Verify that /usr/local/bin is in your PATH, and try `hash -r`.

Comment: {Allah|God|favorite deity} bless you. I would not want to build GCC from sources on Solaris. In fact I need a modern GCC on Solaris and I won't do it. It is too much trouble (for me) to use anything other than what Sun provides.

Comment: Mark, that was the problem exactly. Thanks so much